# Does `tf.data.Dataset.take()` return random sample?

Tags: tensorflow

Different calls of `tf.data.Dataset.take()` return different batches from the given dataset. Are those samples chosen randomly or is there another mechanism at play?

This is all the more confusing that the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#take) makes no reference as to the *randomness* of the sampling.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most probably, you might be using `data.shuffle()` before `tf.data.Dataset.take()`.

Commenting that out should make the iterator behave as intended: take the same results over and over for each iterator run.

-- Or if you used an api that automatically shuffles without asking like `image_dataset_from_directory`

```
shuffle: Whether to shuffle the data. Default: True. 
If set to False, sorts the data in alphanumeric order.
```

You would have to explicitly set `shuffle=False` when creating the dataset

Comment: The code I was using came from [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) notebook. It turns out that `make_csv_dataset()` is shuffling by default, thereby making it somewhat opaque, and thus returned a random batch upon calls to `take()`.

Comment: not exactly: `image_dataset_from_directory` has `shuffle: Whether to shuffle the data. Default: True.` so you have to explicitly set it to false.  **I just added this to the answer

Comment: precisely, there are two ways of implementing shuffle, either directly while reading the data as input using "tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory" or while configuring/defining  the pipeline by using ".shuffle()"

Answer (score 3):

I am a newbie to this domain. But from what I have seen in my notebook is that the take() does pick random samples. For instance, in the image shown here, I had just called image_dataset_from_directory() before calling take(), so no shuffling preceded the take op, still I see different samples on every run. Pls correct me if I am wrong, will help my understanding as well.

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Maybe it happens because you did not supply shuffle=False to image_dataset_from_directory() and it reshuffles training dataset each time? It can be clearly seen that image_dataset_from_directory() does it in its source code (line after comment # Shuffle locally at each iteration).

Comment: you are not wrong, see my edit/comment to the selected answer. `image_dataset_from_directory` sets shuffle=True by default, you have to explicitly set it to False in the args.